# PO Box regex help to match trailing digits

Tags: regex

I have the following regex from regex lib that does a fine job to catch some PO Box variations. The only thing it does not do is to match trailing digits:

**PO Box 123**

Can anyone please help modifying this regex to also match trailing digits?

```
\b[P|p]?(OST|ost)?\.?\s*[O|o|0]?(ffice|FFICE)?\.?\s*[B|b][O|o|0]?[X|x]?\.?\s+[#]?(\d+)\b
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "trailing digits"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the trailing digits in "PO Box 123" are "123", the regex **does** match them. It even captures the number to backreference 3.

There are a large number of flaws in your regex. For instance, it matches `OST|||| 0`.

Might I suggest my own P.O. Box regex?

```
^(?:Post (?:Office )?|P[. ]?O\.? )?Box #?([0-9]+)
```

Enable the option to make `^` and `$` match at line breaks (usually, `/m`), and enable the case insensitive option (usually, `/i`). Don't enable the free-spacing option (usually, `/x`).

Here are some examples of strings it matches:

- Post Office Box #123
- post box 123
- P.O. box 123
- P O Box 123
- Po. box 123
- PO Box 123
- Box 123

The trailing numbers are captured to backreference 1.

Comment: Thanks for that regex. it looks much cleaner. However how do I get it to match just `po box` by itself? I tried `[0-9]*` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @Niner, simply changing `[0-9]+` to `[0-9]*` doesn't work because the space character after the word "Box" is required. Add a `?` quantifier after that space, and you should be good to go. Alternatively, if you don't need to record the number at the end, just replace everything in the regex after "Box" with a word boundary (`\b`).

Answer (score 1):

`\d+` = one or more digits, which you have in there.  Use http://regexpal.com/, it's a life saver.  I tried PO Box 2334328789791297 and it took it, as well as some other variations.  You code looks fine (at a short glance).

Answer (score 0):

I worked from @slevithan’s answer above and added some improvements, which were rejected as edits:

```
 (^|(?:post(al)? *(?:office *)?|p[. ]*o\.? *))box *#? *(\w+)
```

In addition to matching the above cases, it will allow more spaces in between, or lack of spaces and both the short and full permutations of post/postal. Letters are also allowed to be used for the box identifier. Caveat: be sure to enable multi-line and case-insensitive modes on the pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pattern which I created to handle **PO Box** validation will take care of any combination of **Po box** and will also take care of the trailing digits, characters and numbers.

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([P]?(OST|0ST)?\s*[.-]?\s*[O|0]?(FFICE)?\s*[.-]?\s*[B][O|0][X]\s*).*");

Its working fine for me.I have tested it with numerous combination.

please let me know if you find any issue in it.

Note: if you need to come just PO bOx and not the trailing sequence just remove .* from the end and it solve that purpose.I am assuming PO box in upper caps.